# Equivalent ungroup() from R in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, data-wrangling

I try to group by values of `metric` which can be `I` or `M` and make a summe based on the values of `x`. The result should be stored in each row of its respective value. Normally I make it in R with `group` and then `ungroup` but I dont know the equivalent in PysSpark. Any advice?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import last
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [["1", "Amit", "DU", "I", "8", "6"],
        ["2", "Mohit", "DU", "I", "4", "2"],
        ["3", "rohith", "BHU", "I", "5", "3"],
        ["4", "sridevi", "LPU", "I", "1", "6"],
        ["1", "sravan", "KLMP", "M", "2", "4"],
        ["5", "gnanesh", "IIT", "M", "6", "8"],
        ["6", "gnadesh", "KLM", "M","0", "9"]]

columns = ['ID', 'NAME', 'college', 'metric', 'x', 'y']


dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("x",dataframe.x.cast(DoubleType()))
```

This is how the data looks like

```
+---+-------+-------+------+----+---+
| ID|   NAME|college|metric|   x|  y|
+---+-------+-------+------+----+---+
|  1|   Amit|     DU|     I|   8|  6|
|  2|  Mohit|     DU|     I|   4|  2|
|  3| rohith|    BHU|     I|   5|  3|
|  4|sridevi|    LPU|     I|   1|  6|
|  1| sravan|   KLMP|     M|   2|  4|
|  5|gnanesh|    IIT|     M|   6|  8|
|  6|gnadesh|    KLM|     M|0   |  9|
+---+-------+-------+------+----+---+
```

Expected output

```
+---+-------+-------+------+----+---+------+
| ID|   NAME|college|metric|   x|  y| total|
+---+-------+-------+------+----+---+------+
|  1|   Amit|     DU|     I|   8|  6|  18  |
|  2|  Mohit|     DU|     I|   4|  2|  18  |  
|  3| rohith|    BHU|     I|   5|  3|  18  |
|  4|sridevi|    LPU|     I|   1|  6|  18  |
|  1| sravan|   KLMP|     M|   2|  4|  8   |
|  5|gnanesh|    IIT|     M|   6|  8|  8   |
|  6|gnadesh|    KLM|     M|   0|  9|  8   |
+---+-------+-------+------+----+---+------+
```

I tried this but it does not work

```
dataframe.withColumn("total",dataframe.groupBy("metric").sum("x"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do groupby on data and calculate the total value and then join the grouped dataframe with original data

```
metric_sum_df = dataframe.groupby('metric').agg(F.sum('x').alias('total'))
total_df = dataframe.join(metric_sum_df, 'metric')
```

Comment: What would be the differente with this code



`a = daframe.groupBy("metric").agg(sum(col("x")).alias("total"))
data_left = a.join(a, on=['metric'], how='left')`

Comment: The "how" parameter is set "inner" by default. Because 'metric' is extracted from dataframe and all of the metrics are in both data frames there is no difference if you use 'left', 'right', or 'inner' in this case.